# Mlops-v2 accelerator- Issue running "traininng deployment pipeline" from github for project set up with

Tags: azure, github-actions, mlops

Hope you are doing well.

I am currently facing an issue with the execution of my training model pipelines(pipeline.yml for Github and "deploy-model-training-pipeline-classical.yml" for Azure-DevOps) from my ML project set with **Mlops-v2 accelerator**

From  Github:
This pipeline is supposed to execute a number of jobs.As we can in the picture below most of the jobs have been correctly executed except the

**"register-dataset"**.
[image: register job fails]

> The error log specifies /home/runner/xxxxxx/xxxx/mlops/azureml/train/data/data.yml this path cannot be found.

I have tried  different way to fix that i.e moving the data.yml into root folder , modifying the path of the data.yml in the "deploy-model-training-pipeline-classical.yml" file but I am still get the same error mentioned the same error  `/home/runner/xxxxxx/xxxx/mlops/azureml/train/data/data.yml` alghouth I changed the path in the pipeline file and the moved the data.yml in the root.log

[image: error of th register job failed]

Is there anything I need to the update  to make it work?

Below you will see the content of the register YAML file for Github.

```
name: deploy-model-training-pipeline

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  set-env-branch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      config-file: ${{ steps.set-output-defaults.outputs.config-file }}
    steps:
      - id: set-prod-branch
        name: set-prod-branch
        if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'}}
        run: echo "config_env=config-infra-prod.yml" >> $GITHUB_ENV;
      - id: set-dev-branch
        name: setdevbranch
        if: ${{ github.ref != 'refs/heads/main'}}
        run: echo "config_env=config-infra-dev.yml" >> $GITHUB_ENV;
      - id: set-output-defaults
        name: set-output-defaults
        run: |
          echo "config-file=$config_env" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT;
  get-config:
    needs: set-env-branch
    uses: Azure/mlops-templates/.github/workflows/read-yaml.yml@main
    with:
      file_name: ${{ needs.set-env-branch.outputs.config-file}}
  register-environment:
    needs: get-config
    uses: Azure/mlops-templates/.github/workflows/register-environment.yml@main
    with:
      resource_group: ${{ needs.get-config.outputs.resource_group }}
      workspace_name: ${{ needs.get-config.outputs.aml_workspace }}
      environment_file: mlops/azureml/train/train-env.yml
      conda_file: data-science/environment/train-conda.yml
    secrets:
      creds: ${{secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS}}
  register-dataset:
    needs: get-config
    uses: Azure/mlops-templates/.github/workflows/register-dataset.yml@main
    with:
      resource_group: ${{ needs.get-config.outputs.resource_group }}
      workspace_name: ${{ needs.get-config.outputs.aml_workspace }}
      name: UpdateRocheDB
      data_file: mlops/azureml/train/data.yml
    secrets:
      creds: ${{secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS}}
  create-compute:
    needs: [get-config]
    uses: Azure/mlops-templates/.github/workflows/create-compute.yml@main
    with:
      cluster_name: cpu-cluster
      size: Standard_DS3_v2
      min_instances: 0
      max_instances: 4
      cluster_tier: low_priority
      resource_group: ${{ needs.get-config.outputs.resource_group }}
      workspace_name: ${{ needs.get-config.outputs.aml_workspace }}
    secrets:
      creds: ${{secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS}}
  run-model-training-pipeline:
    needs: [get-config, register-environment, register-dataset, create-compute]
    uses: Azure/mlops-templates/.github/workflows/run-pipeline.yml@main
    with:
      resource_group: ${{ needs.get-config.outputs.resource_group }}
      workspace_name: ${{ needs.get-config.outputs.aml_workspace }}
      parameters-file: mlops/azureml/train/pipeline.yml
      job-name: test
    secrets:
      creds: ${{secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS}}
```

From Azure:

the pipeline yaml syntax seems not to be recognized by Azure-devops(see the imgae [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KytPi.png).

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/pipelineJob.schema.json
type: pipeline
experiment_name: fish-health-diagnostics-training
experiment_name: fish-health-diagnostics-training
description: Training Pipeline to train model 0 used to diagnostic the fish health

# <inputs_and_outputs>
inputs:
  input:
    type: uri_file
    path: azureml:fish-health-train-env@latest
  enable_monitoring: 'false'
  table_name: 'fishhealthmonitoring'

outputs:
  train_data:
  val_data:
  test_data:
  trained_model:
  evaluation_output:
  model_info_output_path:
# </inputs_and_outputs>

# <jobs>
settings:
  default_datastore: azureml:workspaceblobstore
  default_compute: azureml:cpu-cluster
  continue_on_step_failure: false

jobs:
  prep_data:
    name: prep_data
    display_name: prep-data
    code: ../../../data-science/src
    command: >-
      python prep.py
      --raw_data ${{inputs.raw_data}}
      --train_data ${{outputs.train_data}}
      --val_data ${{outputs.val_data}}
      --test_data ${{outputs.test_data}}
      --enable_monitoring ${{inputs.enable_monitoring}}
      --table_name ${{inputs.table_name}}
    environment: azureml:fish-health-train-env@latest
    inputs:
      raw_data: ${{parent.inputs.input}}
      enable_monitoring: ${{parent.inputs.enable_monitoring}}
      table_name: ${{parent.inputs.table_name}}
    outputs:
      train_data: ${{parent.outputs.train_data}}
      val_data: ${{parent.outputs.val_data}}
      test_data: ${{parent.outputs.test_data}}

  train_model:
    name: train_model
    display_name: train-model
    code: ../../../data-science/src
    command: >-
      python train.py
      --train_data ${{inputs.train_data}}
      --model_output ${{outputs.model_output}}
    environment: azureml:fish-health-train-env@latest
    inputs:
      train_data: ${{parent.jobs.prep_data.outputs.train_data}}
    outputs:
      model_output: ${{parent.outputs.trained_model}}

  evaluate_model:
    name: evaluate_model
    display_name: evaluate-model
    code: ../../../data-science/src
    command: >-
      python evaluate.py
      --model_name ${{inputs.model_name}}
      --model_input ${{inputs.model_input}}
      --test_data ${{inputs.test_data}}
      --evaluation_output ${{outputs.evaluation_output}}
    environment: azureml:fish-health-train-env@latest
    inputs:
      model_name: "wellfish-model0"
      model_input: ${{parent.jobs.train_model.outputs.model_output}}
      test_data: ${{parent.jobs.prep_data.outputs.test_data}}
    outputs:
      evaluation_output: ${{parent.outputs.evaluation_output}}

  register_model:
    name: register_model
    display_name: register-model
    code: ../../../data-science/src
    command: >-
      python register.py
      --model_name ${{inputs.model_name}}
      --model_path ${{inputs.model_path}}
      --evaluation_output ${{inputs.evaluation_output}}
      --model_info_output_path ${{outputs.model_info_output_path}}
    environment: azureml:fish-health-train-env@latest
    inputs:
      model_name: "wellfish-model0"
      model_path: ${{parent.jobs.train_model.outputs.model_output}}
      evaluation_output: ${{parent.jobs.evaluate_model.outputs.evaluation_output}}
    outputs:
      model_info_output_path: ${{parent.outputs.model_info_output_path}}
# </jobs>
```

Comment: Isn't that an Azure DevOps Pipelines workflow and not GitHub Actions?

Comment: Hi Azeem. Yes you are right . I have updated the post `by including the yaml related to github. I will really appreciate if you can help with this.

Comment: There's no checkout step in your workflow but there are file paths and reusable workflows being used.

Comment: can you be more explicit please? So what should I do.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/actions/checkout.